# solr 6.6 search issue after upgade from 5.5 to 6.6

Tags: java, mysql, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I recently upgrade solrcloud 5.5 to solrcloud 6.6. and all are fine. and the index also copied from the previous version to new version. and I put some configurations from the old version to new version to manage schema and solrconfig.xml and data-config.xml upgrade the MySQL connector to a new version.

right now when we add a new product from the website its uploading with out any error and when I manually executive dataimport it's updating into an index. 
but all this time it's running with the old config files so I linkconfig with the new version and check. the indexing is working and updating the index when entering a new product but the search is not working on a website.

did I do anything wrong in configuration or do I need to add anything additionally for 6.6 version.?

Here is my search handler

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<int name="rows">10</int>

<bool name="preferLocalShards">false</bool>
</lst>
```

Comment: Show us your search requesthandler definition

Comment: @Jeyaprakash please see the search requesthandler. Its updated in my question.